# cakephp using foreach to display different data from different model

Tags: cakephp, foreach

I've been trying to display different data from different model in the same table using foreach. This is the relationship between models

Customer hasMany Job

Job belongsTo Customer

Job hasMany Jobtask

Jobtask belongsTo Job

Jobtask hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

Jobtasksvehicle belongsTo Jobtask and Vehicle

Vehicle hasMany Jobtasksvehicle

This is my controller

```
    function viewsch($id = null) {
    $jobs = $this->Jobtask->find('all', array(

'contain' => array('Customer',
    'Job' => array( 'conditions' => array('Job.id =' => 'Jobtask.job_id')),
        'Jobtasksvehicle'=> array( 'conditions' => array('Jobtasksvehicle.vehicle_id = Vehicle.id')) 

)));
    $this->set(compact('jobs'));        
}
```

This is my view

```
    <div class="jobs index">
<h2><?php __('Jobs Summary');?></h2>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
        <th>Job Id</th>
        <th>Jobtasks ID</th>

        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Vehicle ID</th>


</tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($jobs as $job):
    $class = null;
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $class = ' class="altrow"';
    }
?>
<tr<?php echo $class;?>>
    <td><?php echo $job['Job']['id']; ?>&nbsp;</td>

    <td><?php echo $job['Jobtask']['id']; ?>&nbsp;</td>     

    <td><?php echo $job['Customer']['full_name']; ?>&nbsp;</td>     

    <td><?php echo $job['Jobtasksvehicle']['vehicle_id']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
    <?php echo debug($job); ?>
    </div>
```

I used containable behaviour and when I debug $job I get data from jobtask, job and jobtasksvehicle only, not from customer. But there's no data in jobtasksvehicle. I've already assigned jobtasksvehicle into jobtask. In display only job and jobtask is displaying and for the rest the error saying Undefined index: Customer and Undefined index: vehicle_id.

Please someone help me. It is really important for my project. Thanks.

Note: if it is in SQL what I want to display is like this.

select c.full_name, j.id, t.id, tv.vehicle_id from CUSTOMERS c, JOBS j, JOBTASKS t, JOBTASKSVEHICLES tv where tv.jobtask_id = t.id and t.job_id = j.id and j.customer_id = c.id;

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the output of debug($job) if you change

```
 <td><?php echo $job['Jobtasksvehicle']['vehicle_id']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo debug($job); ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

This will help to show if the data is being retrieved but is being stored in the $job array in  an unexpected way.

Comment: I don't get what you want to say. I just put debug just to know what data are retrieved for $job.